# Can we set priority at Class level in TestNg?

Tags: testng, browser-automation, testng-eclipse, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

```
@Test(priority=2)

public class PositiveTests {
 
    public void loginTest() {
}
@Test(priority=1)

public class NegativeTests {

    public void negativeLoginTest() {
}

TestNg.xml

<classes>
            <class name="com.herokuapp.theinternet.PositiveTests" />
            <class name="com.herokuapp.theinternet.NegativeTests">
</classes>
```

-->>
Will the priority work here? Which class will run first? Positive Test or Negative Test?

Comment: And what are your observations based on what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

priority works for @Test methods inside class.

To run classes in specified order, we need to use preserver-order as'true'

```
 <test name="Regression1" preserve-order="true">
```